# How do I form a union type from arguments in a function

Tags: typescript, tuples

Meta props defintion:

```
interface ITableProps<T> {
  onChange?: (
    pagination: number;
    filters: Record<string, T>;
    section: string[];
  ) => void;
}
```

Expect:
I want to combine the parameters in this function into the interface type of key value,
like this:

```
type ExtractFuncParameters<T> = {
  pagination: number;
  filters: Record<string, T>;
  section: string[];
}
```

But now, I can only get the various types of parameters in the function, I can't get his name, this is my implement:

```
type OnChangeParameters = Parameters<ITableProps<unknown>['onChange']>
type TupleToUnion<T> = T extends Array<infer P> ? P : never;

// number | Record<string, unknown> | string[];
type OnChangeParametersToUnion = TupleToUnion<OnChangeParameters>

// what should I do ?
```